# Fixed sidebar that can be resized vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a bootstrap website. I have two divs in the body, the sidebar and content. I have a content div on the right thats height is dependent on the amount of content in the div. I have a sidebar div on the left that needs to be fixed with a height that is 100% the size of the screen. Therefore when you scroll on in the content div, the sidebar div does not move.

How would I accomplish adding a split handler between the two divs that will allow me to resize the width's of both divs when dragging the splitter horizontally?

I run into an issue when I assign `position: fixed` to the sidebar div.

```
<body>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="splitter"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the `position: fixed;" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  
  /* for testing*/
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* for testing*/
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">test</div>

<div class="right">
  START!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br
  /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br />  Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello
  World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br
  /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br />  Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> Hello World!<br /> END!
  <br />
</div>
```

As for the part "I also need a split handler between the two divs that will allow me to resize the widths of both divs when dragging the splitter horizontally." do you mean be able to separately drag them or do you just want responsiveness?

Comment: I want to be able to drag a vertical border that separates the two divs left or right (horizontally). When you drag the border left or right, the width of both divs change by either becoming smaller or larger depending on which direction you drag the vertical border.